# Rsa C# Encryption and java decryption

Tags: java, c#, encryption, rsa

I am building two applications, one in C# and one in Java, both will use RSA for encryption and decryption.

when I encrypt using JAVA and decrypt  using C# it works flawlessly, the problem occurs when the encryption is done on the C# app and decryption in Java which throws this error:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 64 bytes
```

I'm using RSA with 512 bit RSA to create the keys in both sides, increasing to 1048 changes the error indicating that the size can not be longer than 128 bytes.

Java:

```
public String decrypt(String message, RSAPrivateKey key) {
    try {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

        byte[] dataEncripted =Base64.decodeBase64(message.getBytes());
        byte[] data = cipher.doFinal(dataEncripted);
        return new String(data,"UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

C#:

```
public static string Encrypt(string data, string publicKey)
{
    var sb = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsa.FromXmlString(publicKey);
        byte[] encryptedByteArray;
        byte[] dataToEncrypt;

        dataToEncrypt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        encryptedByteArray = rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, false);
        sb = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedByteArray);
    }
}
```

What I have noticed is that the process that works, JAVA --> C#, when encrypted, the array goes from 0 to 63 (64 bytes), but in the other process C# --> JAVA, the encrypted data goes from 0 to 64 (65 bytes)

Here a image to show in java after decode the arrayBytes number :

[Bytes java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARUWc.jpg)

How can I make the RSA C# provider to generate an array of bytes equal to the one in Java? or any insight on how to solve this?

Comment: Based on the [MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx) you seem to be missing a `UnicodeEncoding` (specially considering that you treat the string as UTF-8 on Java). Have you tried that?

Comment: @Av4t4r: that is an obvious mistake but I think not the one causing the  error.

Comment: General advice: **Always use a fully qualified Cipher string.** `Cipher.getInstance("RSA");` may result in different ciphers depending on the default security provider. Nowadays, you should use OAEP instead of the default PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. So you should probably use `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");`

Comment: Do you mean that the *Base64-encoded* string is 65 characters long? That's usually not possible, because the 65th character cannot represent a full byte and there should be some padding characters to get to a length which is divisible by 4. Are you sure that there isn't some junk character from somewhere else in your code?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I going to add a image where show you. the image is in the question body

Comment: Please show an example public key and an example ciphertext (Base64-encoded).